# CSS Max-Width in IE8

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

For my input, which can either have `classname="half"` or `"half.not-placeholder-value"`, Firebug shows both inputs to have a set, fixed width of `25em`.

```
input.half, input.half.not-placeholder-value {
    max-width: 25em;
}
```

Yet, according to Developer Tools, IE8 doesn't seem to use this particular `max-width` attribute. I say "doesn't seem to use" since Firefox's behavior differs with IE8 with respect to this attribute.

But the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/max-width) say that IE7 supports `max-width`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure `max-width` makes sense without any kind of variable width (such as `width:100%`)

Comment: Hmm.. But, in Firefox, it creates a fixed length for my inputs - my desired behavior. Without max-width, the input sizes vary based on either class.

Comment: Have you also tried adding the width: 100%; attribute just to see if it works?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah, I just tested "width:25em" and that worked in IE8, as well as Firefox.

Comment: That will make all inputs 25em wide even if they could be smaller. If that is okay with you, great.  If not, try width: 100%; max-width: 25em;

Comment: http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/5/How-max-width-fails-in-IE8.html

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah - want to post answer for credit?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not really an IE8 issue since IE8 *does* support the max-width attribute but only when given a defined width first.

```
input.half, input.half.not-placeholder-value {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use IE8 css with `width`? First part targets IE, second part undoes it for IE9+.

```
input.half, input.half.not-placeholder-value {
    max-width: 25em;
    width:25em\9; /* IE 8 */
}
:root input.half, input.half.not-placeholder-value {
    width:inherit\9; /* IE 9+ */
}
```