# Trouble with css max-width in ie8

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

I am having a problem with using the css max-width property in ie8 to size a column in a gridview.

Here is my code:

In a css file:

```
.gridMaxMinWidth
{
        max-width: 300px;
        min-width: 100px;
        word-wrap: break-word
}
```

I then put this attribute into the BoundField of the GridView in the aspx page:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" 
ItemStyle-CssClass="gridMaxMinWidth" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource12" />
```

In IE10, the column shows up at 300px wide with the text wrapped nicely, but in IE8, the column retains it long length with no wrapping. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392265/css-max-width-in-ie8

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it a width as well, in this case width: 100% would be best.

Comment: Does the 'width: 100%' need to go in the .gridMaxMinWidth element or as an attribute in the BoundField?

Comment: It should go in the .gridMaxMinWidth CSS. Sidenote that IE8 is (to my knowledge) the only browser that needs the width: 100%.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. This code works in IE10, but in both IE8 and IE9, the column width isn't being shortened. I've cleared the cache, btw, and it still has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
```